# kubectl run fails failed to discover supported resources:

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

just setup a 3 node cluster on gke and attempted to use kubectl run to deploy a container.

I get

error: failed to discover supported resources: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: an error on the server ("service unavailable") has prevented the request from succeeding

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the cluster might be in an *upgrading* state.

For that, you can use the [Google SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) and determine if it's being upgraded:

```
gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE/--region REGION
```

If not, check that you're actually pointing your `kubectl` tool to correct cluster:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

`gcloud` has the advantage that it can automatically configure your `kubectl` client:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE/--region REGION
```

If the cluster is being in that state for quite a long time (usually several hours), there might be an error in the cluster backend ([since GKE is a managed implementation of Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/)). If that's the case, you might want to reach out to [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/#support-plans) to review your case.